# Count of all groups meeting a conditional statement

Tags: stata, survey

I came up with a solution this weekend while working on creating a post that fits the SO guidelines. I'm sorry for giving you guys nothing to work with in the first post.

My solution was to collapse the data I was interested in into a dataset of counts and then tab for those groups meeting the conditional expression:

Example:

Say I want to analyze political party affiliation among age groups by both race and sex. Before I get any further I want to make sure I have the cell counts I need to run a proper analysis. I want to check how many races have at least 10 observations of political party for each age group and how many age groups by sex have at least 10 observations of political party. And I am too lazy to count the number of groups that meet this condition from a straight-up tab so I want Stata to do it for me (essential with large survey data with many many groupings (like counties or zipcodes)).

Using a subset of the General Social Survey 2014 dataset available at [U of Wisconsin stats site](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/sfs/sfs-files.htm)(https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/sfs/sfs-files.htm)

```
use https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/sfs/gss_sample.dta

* Streamline dataset
keep sex age race partyid 

*Create age group variable
gen agegroup = .
replace agegroup=1 if age<=25
replace agegroup=2 if age>25 & age <=35
replace agegroup=3 if age>35 & age<=45
replace agegroup=4 if age>45 & age <=55
replace agegroup=5 if age>55 & age <=65
replace agegroup=6 if age>65
label var agegroup "Age Groups"
lab def grouplab 1 "25 or younger" 2 "26 to 35" 3 "36 to 45" 4 "46 to 55" 5 "56 to 65" 6 "65 and older"
lab val agegroup grouplab


collapse (count) numparty=partyid, by(agegroup race)
list
tab agegroup race if numparty>10
```

* the only age group of black respondents with at least 10 responses to political party is ages 26 to 35; all white age groups have at least 10 responses to party id

```
clear
use https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/sfs/gss_sample.dta

* Streamline dataset
keep sex age race partyid 

*Create age group variable
gen agegroup = .
replace agegroup=1 if age<=25
replace agegroup=2 if age>25 & age <=35
replace agegroup=3 if age>35 & age<=45
replace agegroup=4 if age>45 & age <=55
replace agegroup=5 if age>55 & age <=65
replace agegroup=6 if age>65
label var agegroup "Age Groups"
lab def grouplab 1 "25 or younger" 2 "26 to 35" 3 "36 to 45" 4 "46 to 55" 5 "56 to 65" 6 "65 and older"
lab val agegroup grouplab


collapse (count) numparty=partyid, by(agegroup sex)
list
tab agegroup sex if numparty>10
```

* 5/6 age groups among males have more than 10 responses to party id and 6/6 female age groups have more than 10 responses

The examples are a bit nonsensical but the structure is what I came up with and works with my real data. Please give me your feedback. I know this was probably obvious to most of you and there is likely a much more elegant solution.

Original post:

---

I am new to Stata from R and having trouble tackling a seemingly simple problem. Dealing with survey data, I need to know how many groups have 50+ observations for each year of my survey. I don't care about the value of the observations, just whether or not they answered the question item (non-missing). Ideal output would be a single number (i.e. "33" if 33 groups of a total 35 met the condition). I've tried count and sum and all manner of "by" statements.

I'm hoping for something like this, where 33 groups had 50+ obs in year one, 20 groups had 50+ obs in year 2 and 29 had 50+ obs in year 3:

| Year 1 | Year 2| Year 3|
    33       20      29

I will post some fake smaller data when I figure out how to do so.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please read [ask] and provide us with a [mcve] using Stata's `dataex` command. We cannot help you if we don't see an example of your data. Also, provide us with the code you have tried. Generic statements like "_I've tried count and sum and all manner of "by" statements"_ are not helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your honest feedback i know it was a badly written question.

Comment: Is there a specific question here? You seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: The only thing you can do more 'elegantly' here is to use `egen agegroup = cut(age), at(0,26,36,46,56,66,89) label` instead of the individual `replace` commands.

Comment: @PearlySpencer My personal objection to `cut()` is that what happens at the limits has to be established by looking at the `egen` code or the documentation. That may sound reasonable, but even more attractive is any method in which the criteria are more transparent.

Comment: @NickCox Can you elaborate? I never had to look at the `egen` code. I do not think I understand your objection.

Comment: 25, 35, 45, 55, 65 are class limits and the OP wants them to be included in the class below. That's fair enough but it is really not obvious that `cut()` does that. It is entirely possible to have classes that run less than 25, 25 or more but less than 35., etc. That is, are the classes (-infinity, x1), [x1, x2), ... or (-infinity, x1], (x1, x2], ... cut does what the OP wants but the problem is for the reader who is told or who sees in the code `egen, cut()` and needs to know what that does. Naturally a careful reporter will explain somewhere which inequalities are `<` and which `<=`.

Comment: This is a big issue with integer variables like age in years where many values will coincide with bin limits and results can be sensitive to which rule is used for those cases.

Comment: Yes, i see your point although i never had a problem with it. I always need a bit of experimentation to get it right though.

Comment: I argued against `cut()` at the beginning. I think the syntax `at()` is a bad choice. There is a paper forthcoming in _Stata Journal_ 18(3) 2018 on binning and it's not even a method mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Irregular classifications are best done totally explicitly. Here is one way to do that: it's not especially concise, but it should be fairly instructive and easy to follow.

```
* toy dataset for any one who wants to play 
clear
input age 
15
25
35
45
55
65
75 
end 

* OP's method 
gen agegroup = .
replace agegroup=1 if age<=25
replace agegroup=2 if age>25 & age <=35
replace agegroup=3 if age>35 & age<=45
replace agegroup=4 if age>45 & age <=55
replace agegroup=5 if age>55 & age <=65
replace agegroup=6 if age>65

* another way to do it 
gen also = 6 
local limits 65 55 45 35 25 
quietly forval j = 5(-1)1 { 
    gettoken this limits : limits 
    replace also = `j' if age <= `this' 
} 

* compare results
list
```

Comment: Why was this question re-opened? There is nothing here that can be answered.

Comment: @PearlySpencer The OP wants feedback on their code. That's not a precise question, but feedback is entirely possible: you gave some yourself. Evidently others disagreed with you and they're unlikely to be reading this as many members not following particular tags are just watching review queues. (I don't recall whether I voted to re-open.)

Comment: I gave feedback in comments because a full answer is not possible. There is no specific question here. With the exception of your vote, the people who disagreed and voted to re-open the question are android developers...

Comment: The system is imperfect and sometimes democracy yields what one thinks are wrong decisions. Sound familiar? (I disagree on the specifics here, as the thread can be made a little useful and interesting for the OP and others too.)